# Issues with encoding plus sign (executing Poco::URI::setQueryParameters and Poco::URI::getQueryParameters gives unexpected result)

Tags: c++, url-encoding, poco-libraries

Suppose I have a URI parameter with value, which contains plus signs (`+`) and other special chars.

When I execute `URI::setQueryParameters` and then `URI::getQueryParameters`, the resulted value is not the same as the original one - all special chars are fine, except the plus sign.

Could you, please, advice what is the **conventional** way to do this?

---

**Workaround:** explicitly invoke `URI::encode` with `reserved` containing plus sign. But this doesn't seem to be right, it really **looks like** a workaround.
Anyway, **if this is the correct way to achieve this**, what symbols should I include in `reserved`, if I want to avoid such surprises in the future?

**Other observations:** `URI::decode` has a parameter named `plusAsSpace` (defaulted to `false`), but this does not help. `URI::getQueryParameters` replaces `+` with  (space) before calling `URI::decode`.

---

Here's a sample code:

```
const std::string value_with_plus_signs = "value+with+plus+signs";
Poco::URI::QueryParameters out_params;
out_params.push_back(std::make_pair("param", value_with_plus_signs));

Poco::URI uri("path");
uri.setQueryParameters(out_params);

const auto in_params = uri.getQueryParameters();
std::cout << "Expected: '" << value_with_plus_signs << "', received: '" 
    << in_params.front().second << "'" << std::endl;
```

output: `Expected: 'value+with+plus+signs', received: 'value with plus signs'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was fixed in Poco (notice that '+' is added to the symbols that are encoded by default):

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1260
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/commit/c32e683b6c00950ddfce817dfe8f3fc0b6846455

I tested your code with poco 1.7.9p2 and I got the correct results.